# UISwtich is triggring another UISwitch event in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I am using `UISwitch` in `PFTableView`. When I switch ON one UISwitch it triggers another switch in different cell. Here is the code for `PFTableViewCell`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject ? ) - > PFTableViewCell {
  var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tempHsCell") as!NearestHsCell!

    if cell == nil {
      cell = NearestHsCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "tempHsCell")
    }
    /*Assign Object to cell*/
  cell.hotspot = object
  return cell
}

// Code for UISwtich Action  
@
IBAction func userSelectHotspot(sender: UISwitch) {
  if hotspotSwitch.on {
    selectedHotspot[(self._hotspot ? .objectId) !] = self._hotspot
  } else {
    let key = self._hotspot!.objectId!
      selectedHotspot.removeValueForKey(key)
  }
}
```

[image: Output of tableView]

Comment: you should control your switch by storing your switch state in the cell's object instead letting it default, the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ` stuff is overlap your non coded switch, there maybe other way to do but im not sure :D

Comment: Are both switches on screen when this happens, or do you have to scroll to discover the wrongly triggered switch? If so, it is because of cell reuse as others said. You should reset the cells to a clean state every time. Ideally, assigning your `hotspot` property could take care of updating cell state by using a property observer.

Comment: @NicolasMiari I have to scroll down to view the second switch.But the code is in IBAction.Can you please elaborate your answer in code.

Answer (score 1):

This is because table cells get reused with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. You need to allow for this and reset the switch every time.

Comment: I don't think this could be the solution .

Comment: hello @Michael. Can you please show how can i achieve this in code.

Answer (score 1):

```
//need to maintain Switch status of every cell , using datasource , initially datasource initialize with all elements "NO"

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPathindexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject ? ) - > PFTableViewCell {
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tempHsCell") as!NearestHsCell!

 if cell == nil {
   cell = NearestHsCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "tempHsCell")
}
/*Assign Object to cell*/

if arrDatasource.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String == "YES" {
  switch.on = true
 } else {
   switch.on = false
}
cell.hotspot = object
switch.tag = indexpath.row
return cell
}

@IBAction func userSelectHotspot(sender: UISwitch) {
  if hotspotSwitch.on {
    arrDatasource.setObject("YES", atIndexedSubscript:sender.tag)
    selectedHotspot[(self._hotspot ? .objectId) !] = self._hotspot
 } else {
   arrDatasource.setObject("NO", atIndexedSubscript:sender.tag)
   let key = self._hotspot!.objectId!
   selectedHotspot.removeValueForKey(key)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, as per your comment:

> @NicolasMiari I have to scroll down to view the second switch.But the
>   code is in IBAction.Can you please elaborate your answer in code. –
>   Nishant Dongare

...it seems that the cell is being reused, and so the switch stays "on" since when the cell was used to display the row at index #0 and you tapped it.

To avoid any previous state to persist when you reuse a cell, you should always reset it prior to reuse:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject ? ) - > PFTableViewCell {
  var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tempHsCell") as!NearestHsCell!

    if cell == nil {
        // Cell is brand new, no need to clean up:

        cell = NearestHsCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "tempHsCell")
    }
    else{
        // Cell is being reused; reset all subviews/state etc.

        cell.switch.on = false
    }

    /*Assign Object to cell*/
    cell.hotspot = object

    return cell
}
```

*(As a side note, I **strongly** recommend that you switch to using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_: forIndexPath:)` instead; it automatically does the instantiation for you in case there is no cell to reuse in the pool, so your code becomes shorter and simpler)*

Alternatively, you could make the cell take care of it when you assign the model object:

```
class NearestCell : UITableViewCell {

    var hotSpot:<(The Class of hotspot)> {
        didSet {
            // (Update state of the switch, cell's title label, etc.
            // based on the new value of hotspot.)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello @NicolasMiari . I tried both the approaches.  `if cell == nil {
        // Cell is brand new, no need to clean up:

        cell = NearestHsCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "tempHsCell")
    }
    else{
        // Cell is being reused; reset all subviews/state etc.

        cell.switch.on = false
    }`
It is working. But the down side is when i scroll down and again scroll up the selected Swtich is also get deselected.

Comment: That is because your data model does not "remember" the switch state. My guess is, when you flip the switch the hot spot object associated with the cell should store that state. Next time you assign that same hot spot object to a new cell, that cell must update it's subviews accordingly (i.e., set the switch on). Does it make sense?

Comment: Cells get reused for efficiency; at any time only the numberof instances  needed on scrren exists. Your cells must be able to restore whatever state is associated with displaying a given row of your data model.

Comment: In your case, you should modify a property of the cell's hot spot when the switch changes state (inside the associated @IBAction), so that next time you assign that hot spot to a different, reused cell, it can set *its* switch to the appropriate state and maintain consistency.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with multiple UISwitches inside a set of UITableViewCell cells. It was the "addTarget" which got stacked on top of them others. Removing them before resolved it.

```
cell.optionSwitch.on = configManager.distanceMetric;
[cell.optionSwitch removeTarget:self action:nil 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.optionSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(updateDistanceMetric:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```